# How to read Windows user and pass it to web browser?

Tags: windows, browser, webbrowser-control, oracle-apex

is it possible to read user logged in Windows OS (Windows 10) and pass it to web browser or some application in web browser (Oracle APEX)?

What I exactly need: I have some landing page with number of links which represents different applications. Landing page is made with Oracle APEX. The number of links is to big and when someone opens the page, there is too many links to be easily readible and user-friendly. Since the most users use only a few applications, idea is to show them only those application links.

I can make database table with user/application privileges, but I need to have possibility to read user which is logged in Windows OS.

Comment: Probably you can if use Microsoft IIS in front of ORDS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.edocr.com/v/lv1rvxvx/nielsdebruijn/Single-Sign-On-for-Oracle-Application-Express-APEX

Comment: These links look promissing. Still I need some time to study it. Thanks. I will post my findings